# Convert a logical matrix to an integer matrix

Tags: r, matrix

I have the following `logical` matrix:-

```
k <- matrix(c(T,T,F,F,T,F,T,F,T,T,F,F,T,F,T,F,T,T,T,T,F,F,F,F,F), 5)
```

However, when I do the following:-

```
z <- as.integer(k)
```

I get an `integer` vector rather than an `integer` matrix:-

```
[1] 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0
```

I want it to get a matrix like following:-

```
k <- matrix(c(1,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0), 5)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use unary `+`:

```
+k
##      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
## [1,]    1    0    0    0    0
## [2,]    1    1    0    1    0
## [3,]    0    0    1    1    0
## [4,]    0    1    0    1    0
## [5,]    1    1    1    1    0
```

Answer (score 4):

We may need to use `[]` to keep the dim intact

```
z <- k
z[] <- as.integer(k)
```

---

Or another option is to do the `dim` assignment

```
z <- as.integer(k)
dim(z) <- dim(k)
```

---

Or without doing the `dim` changes, can just multiply by `1` to coerce to numeric

```
z <- k * 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative:

```r
storage.mode(k) <- "integer"
```

Answer (score 1):

```r
k <- matrix(c(T,T,F,F,T,F,T,F,T,T,F,F,T,F,T,F,T,T,T,T,F,F,F,F,F), 5)
res <- +k
res
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
#> [1,]    1    0    0    0    0
#> [2,]    1    1    0    1    0
#> [3,]    0    0    1    1    0
#> [4,]    0    1    0    1    0
#> [5,]    1    1    1    1    0
```

<sup>Created on 2021-10-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>